# Rabbit VCS on Ubuntu 18.04 - not showing menu in Nautilus

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, rabbitvcs

I'm having problems using Rabbit VCS integration with Nautilus under Ubuntu 18.04. Installation from the Bionic Beaver PPA does not seem to work at all while using the procedure presented on their web page, as there is not a candidate for 18.04.

Any hints on how to make it running?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make RabitVCS working again on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS by copying its python extension to special directory inside your home folder:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions

cp /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py \
~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

Then restart Nautilus (Files) with

```
nautilus -q
```

and enjoy:

[image: RabbitVCS on Nautilus 3.26 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

I hope it is fully-functional.

---

Notes:
1. if you need only Mercurial you can use `tortoisehg-nautilus` package.
2. if you see two RabbitVCS menu sections then remove python extension from home folder with `rm ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ! step forward, one step back. I run into the Python problems now:

ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: 'No module named gi._gobject')

(nautilus:12724): Nautilus-Python-WARNING **: 17:23:36.076: pygobject initialization failed

(nautilus:12724): Nautilus-Python-WARNING **: 17:23:36.076: nautilus_python_init_python failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pczekalski/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py", line 63, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject, Gtk, GdkPixbuf

Comment: It is strange because of the dependencies: `python-gi` and `python-nautilus` should be installed with `rabbitvcs-nautilus` (see [1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/rabbitvcs-nautilus) and [2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/rabbitvcs-core), [3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-nautilus)). If it is not enough you can additionally install `python3-gi`.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply. It seems that I'm forced to use Python 2.7 because of the PlatformIO requirements: 
`pczekalski@n317-pc10:~$ which python
/home/pczekalski/.platformio/penv/bin/python
pczekalski@n317-pc10:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1`

I just wonder if there is any way to force Nautilus to use other Python (i.e. 3.6) to run extensions (including Rabbit)?

Comment: I think, you should remove PlatformIO folder from $PATH variable (somewhere in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`).

Comment: Ha, that did the trick! Rabbit works now but ... PlatformIO Core is dead ;-). I'll experiment with path order, possibly that will help. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: On my system PlatformIO is installed inside Atom. Atom is installed with Ubuntu-Make. Atom's executable is located in `/home/norbert/.local/share/umake/bin/atom` (it is in PATH as `...:/home/norbert/.local/share/umake/bin:...`). You can try to make something similar. If RabbitVCS problem is solved you can [accept and/or vote](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) for my answer.

Comment: Actually adding PlatformIO path to the ~/.profile was a solution to one of the PlatformIO bugs as a temporary solution. Surprisingly it works now (after removing from PATH), possibly it was fixed by developers. I'm using PlatformIO with Visual Studio Code (sorry, I'm a former Windows developer and Win->Linux refugee ;-) ). Thank you for your great support.

Comment: Did all  the steps, not errors but still not working for me.

Comment: @Ya what is your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Comment: It can be an issue with your repository size. I just found out, my SVN repo is so huge it takes some 5min to let Rabbit "index" the content. Then the menu appears. So check, please, it may be your issue. Just give nautilus some time to do its job (I believe it is asynchronous).

Comment: Thank you. It helps, but somehow `nautilus -q` was not sufficient on my computer, as the context menu was still not shown after following the procedure.

Finally, I had to do `sudo killall nautilus` which restarts Nautilus anyway, and I could see the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

To install rabbitvcs: | Update rabbitvcs-nautilus3 to rabbitvcs-nautilus package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
```