# Rabbit VCS on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - not showing menu in Nautilus

Tags: 18.04, rabbitvcs

I'm having the same issue with RabbitVCS as this post: [Rabbit VCS on Ubuntu 18.04 - not showing menu in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062947/rabbit-vcs-on-ubuntu-18-04-not-showing-menu-in-nautilus).  However, I've followed the accepted answer and the comments, and I still do not get the RabbitVCS context menu.

[image]

UPDATE: Below are the results of the commands from the other post that I followed.  Also, if it makes a difference, I'm running inside VirtualBox.

```
~$ aptitude search rabbitvcs
p   rabbitvcs-cli      - Command line interface for RabbitVCS                                     
i A rabbitvcs-core     - Easy version control                                                     
p   rabbitvcs-gedit    - Gedit extension for RabbitVCS                                            
i   rabbitvcs-nautilus - Nautilus extension for RabbitVCS

~$ ll ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 2 alager alager  4096 Jan 28 14:20 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 alager alager  4096 Jan 28 14:20 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 alager alager 24082 Jan 28 14:20 RabbitVCS.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 alager alager 20384 Jan 28 14:20 RabbitVCS.pyc
```

Update2:

`~$ python /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py
/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py:63: PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject, Gtk, GdkPixbuf`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rabbit VCS on Ubuntu 18.04 - not showing menu in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062947/rabbit-vcs-on-ubuntu-18-04-not-showing-menu-in-nautilus). Please try this method again. I have just tested it on clean 18.04 LTS VM and it works as described.

Comment: @N0rbert See the update in the OP.  Did I do something incorrectly?

Comment: To be completely sure remove user's python script with `rm -rf ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/`, install all updates with `sudo apt-get update` + `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and then reinstall RabbitVCS with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall rabbitvcs-nautilus`. Then logout and login back.

Comment: @N0rbert Nope, that didn't do it either.

Comment: Please manually execute Rabbit's python script with `python /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py` and show error message (if any). Also check `~/.xsession-errors` for python errors.

Comment: @N0rbert see update2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88966/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-aaron).

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the same procedure as the [other question's accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1062953) as you mentioned, but try killing Nautilus process instead of restarting it.

---

Install rabbitvcs-nautilus

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
```

Create a local folder (under user home) to store the python extension

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

Copy the RabbitVCS python extension to new local folder

```
cp /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py \
~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

Try restarting Nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

*Optional*: **If** you still cannot view the context menu, then try killing Nautilus, which should get usually restarted automatically.

```
sudo killall nautilus
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't get it working, I'd recommend compiling it from source (AFTER purging the installed packages). I was never able to get the repo version working myself without some serious problems. One big problem being that when viewing logs, the comparison feature between revisions always told me both files were identical. Mmm, no, they are not...

The version in the Ubuntu repos is quite old compared to the newest (17.x)

https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs

The client you want is nautilus-3.0 if that's what you're using.

The instructions are all there. If you're running a newer (2.7 up, I believe) version of Python, in some of the relevant files it might be worth changing "import simplejson" to "import json as simplejson" in the source files whereever "import simplejson" appears, and then recompile/reinstall. This is because Python has changed its library to *have* "simplejson" as the default "json" library.

Comment: I followed the instructions from github...no dice. :(  Their PPA doesn't work either with the current version (bionic) of ubuntu.

Comment: If you want, I can try and get a script that performs everything for you tomorrow to install it. It definitely works for me on various distributions including Ubuntu... Might be something left over that is causing an issue?

Comment: That's a tricky one, since now it "magically" started worked, while I was following N0rbert's suggestions.  It's resolved, but not sure how/why.

Comment: Seems like a case of Schrodinger's bug.

Let me know if you do get the issue with compared revisions in the log saying "file is identical" though, that's the main issue I had with the repo version which is resolved by the version on GitHub.