# There is no context menu after installing rabbitVCS in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, rabbitvcs

I installed the rabbitVCS-nautilus ver 0.18-3 on ubuntu 22.04 like the following:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus

I have tried this {https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062947/rabbit-vcs-on-ubuntu-18-04-not-showing-menu-in-nautilus} but it not working. The rabbitVCS is still not appeared on the context menu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As Rabbit VCS isn't a part of the Ubuntu OS, you likely will not find particularly good support here. I'd suggest that you work directly with the Rabbit VCS team over on Github: [there's an open bug that seems to relate to your particular issue here.](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/issues/348)